# Google Map markers retrieved from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

When the markers are created they are shown immediately on the map and in the database.
But when I delete it, it will stay in the map until I update the view. I want to remove it in the map instantly but no idea how. 
Any suggestions?

This is how i retrieve data from firebase and show markers in a **for cicle**

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("userdata")
ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    ref.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if (snapshot.value as? [String:Any]) != nil {
            for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                guard let Dict = rest.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                    continue
                }
                let latitude = Dict["latitude"]
                let longitude = Dict["longitude"]
                let username = Dict["username"]
                let model = Dict["firstname"]
                let marker = GMSMarker()
                marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: longitude as! CLLocationDegrees)
                marker.title = username as? String
                marker.snippet = model as? String
                mapView.selectedMarker = marker
                marker.map = mapView
            }
        }
    })
})
```

I also put the function i use to create the marker

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didLongPressAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        print("You tapped at \(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)")
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Crea Marker", message: "...", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert) //Replace UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert by UIAlertControllerStyle.alert
        let DestructiveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Annulla", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) {
            (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            print("Annulla")
        }

        // Replace UIAlertActionStyle.Default by UIAlertActionStyle.default
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Crea", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
            (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("userdata")
            let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
            let displayName = currentUser?.displayName
            let post = ["username": displayName,"uid": currentUser?.uid as Any,"latitude": coordinate.latitude,"longitude": coordinate.longitude, "firstname":"test"]
            ref.childByAutoId().setValue(post)

            print("Entra")
        }

        alertController.addAction(DestructiveAction)
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

**N.B. Im deleting data manually from Firebase**

**EDIT:**
[This is a gif for a better explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juve9.gif)

Comment: Where is your code for remove marker ?

Comment: im only deleting from database manually

Comment: Are you deleting manually from Firebase ?

Comment: Yes just for test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my exprience you are calling firebase data again or refresing it agin

if YES than you have to clear your map with below methods

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("userdata")
ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    ref.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if (snapshot.value as? [String:Any]) != nil {

           //Here Before adding any other marker You have to clear your MAP 
           mapView.clear()

            for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                guard let Dict = rest.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                    continue
                }
                let latitude = Dict["latitude"]
                let longitude = Dict["longitude"]
                let username = Dict["username"]
                let model = Dict["firstname"]
                let marker = GMSMarker()
                marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: longitude as! CLLocationDegrees)
                marker.title = username as? String
                marker.snippet = model as? String
                mapView.selectedMarker = marker
                marker.map = mapView
            }
        }
    })
})
```

It will solve your problem with old marker there on MAP

But if you are not refreshing data use this mapView.clear() method where you want to refresh this or remove marker.

Check below link for ref :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker

Comment: Thanks for answer, but if i delete data from db the marker stay in its position  , so is the same

Comment: Yes, someone talk me about a "cheat": add markers in a dictionary and compare values with the database. In java people use hashmap but i don't know how in swift

Comment: Have you try this 

`//Here Before adding any other marker You have to clear your MAP `
           `mapView.clear()`

Comment: can you share that screen may be its your current location marker ?